# How to convert JSON array from REST API to an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

From my backend I receive message like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2018-12-31"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "standard": null,
            "capacity": 7,
            "description": null,
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "date": "2018-12-08"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "standard": null,
            "capacity": 7,
            "description": null,
        }
    ]
]
```

I want to map this response to list of 2 objects, so I created class:

```
export class Response {

  id: string;
  date: string;
  standard: string;
  capacity: number;
  description: string;
}
```

I my method, where I calling a service I tried different methods, and even backendData.forEach doesn't work - Angular doesn't recognize backendData as an array.

```
getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(backendData=>{
      //how to convert  backendData to an array of Response[]?
    })
  }
```

I will be very grateful for every help I have been stuck with this for couple of time.

Comment: Converting data can sometimes be really painful. I use this decorator-based library ([typestack/class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)) for conversions. The authors also have a validation library too. Strongly suggested.

Comment: Okay, so quick question, what does ```backendData``` look like? I mean the response looks like an array that contains an array of objects?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: You should log backendData and check what you're getting, I think it's a response object so you will get the array from response body like backendData.body and you need to parse it also, so first log it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps

```
getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(backendData=> {
        //how to convert  backendData to an array of Response[]?
        return backendData.map(array => Object.assign(array[0], array[1]))
    })
}
```

I'm not sure that you really can convert to Response type this array, because your `id` is string, but in response you got number, also you got nullable `description` and `standard` in response